# Form text field default to disappear on focus and user input to remain on form corrections

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Ok I have this neat little piece of JQuery I have been working on.  It takes the text fields title as the default text...so as to allow me to use the value for its intended purpose.  On focus, the title disappears and allows the user to input.  On blur, it works great...keeping the input from the user.  The problem becomes the fact I cant get the "value" to work!  For example, when a user submits a form with errors, it spits them back to the form, and even though I have the $_POST variable in the "value" to avoid the user having to re-enter it, its still putting the "title" portion of the text input.  To avoid confusion, the input from the user is still processed great.  **Im just trying to get the "value" to work as the default text in case there are form errors.**

The field is like so:

```
<input id="registerField" class="idleField" title="First Name" type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['firstname'])){echo htmlentities($_POST['firstname']);}?>" />
```

Heres the JQuery:

```
$("input[type=text][title]").each(function() {
  $(this).val($(this).attr("title"));
  if($.trim($(this).val()) == "")
    $(this).val($(this).attr("title"));
  $(this)
    .focus(function() {
      if($(this).val() == $(this).attr("title")) $(this).val("");
    })
    .blur(function() {
      if($.trim($(this).val()) == "") $(this).val($(this).attr("title"));
    });
});
```

I also am more than welcoming scraping my strategy for anything you guys might have that works great for you!  Thanks a ton for the help!

Comment: Yeah changing the value causes issues, seen [infield labels](http://fuelyourcoding.com/scripts/infield/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the HTML5 `placeholder` attribute, and save yourself ;p

Comment: why did I never hear about this haha

Comment: Quick question though...are most browsers now compatible with this feature?

Comment: Modern one yes, I think just ie9 is not yet... but out there is plenty of jquery plugins to fallback